# I'm printing each edge with the source and destination but they are repeated when I use getEdgeCount() in mxgraph java

Tags: java, mxgraph

I'm using the following function to show me each edge in the graph with its source and destination. However, I noticed that some edges appear out of nowhere.

```
public void showEdges()
    {
        Object[] list = graph.getChildVertices(graph.getDefaultParent());
        for(int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
        {
            mxICell vertex = (mxICell) list[i];
            for (int j =0; j<vertex.getEdgeCount(); j++)
            {
                mxICell edge = vertex.getEdgeAt(j);
                String destination =(String) (edge.getTerminal(false)).getValue();
                System.out.println("vertex-" + i + " is connected to " +
                        destination + " with weight " + (String)edge.getValue());
            }
        }
         
    }
```

What I have drawn is in this link:
https://pin.it/7b0Qh7v

The output :

```
vertex-0 is connected to 0 with weight 2
vertex-0 is connected to 2 with weight 15
vertex-1 is connected to 2 with weight 17
vertex-2 is connected to 2 with weight 17
vertex-2 is connected to 2 with weight 15
```

What I expected was :

```
vertex-0 is connected to 0 with weight 2
vertex-0 is connected to 2 with weight 15
vertex-1 is connected to 2 with weight 17
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: What's the default parent you are passing in here? I think your `graph.getChildVertices()` method has an issue. Can you provide more context to that?

Comment: @k9yosh Each time I add a node, I call this method : Object v = graph.insertVertex(graph.getDefaultParent(), null,  " Name " , 30, 30,
                60, 60); These are the only parts of the code where I call the default parent.

Comment: I was asking for a bit of context about the `graph.getChildVertices()` method. And what this `graph.getDefaultParent()` means. Because as you can see, your Vertex's are going past 1. That means your `Object[] list` get's unwanted/erroneous data

Comment: @k9yosh it returns the first child of the root in the model, that is, the first or default layer of the diagram.

Comment: @k9yosh I could solve the problem and I showed the solution below. You actually gave me the motivation to think in a different way. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Now I know the problem with my code.
The method getEdgesAt(int index) returns all edges whether they are incoming or outgoing and what I want in order for my method to work is only the outgoing edges.
I replaced the method with this :

```
    public void getEdges()
    {
        Object[] list = graph.getChildVertices(graph.getDefaultParent());
        for(int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
        {
            mxICell vertex = (mxICell) list[i];
            Object[] edges = graph.getEdges(vertex, graph.getDefaultParent(), false, true, true);
            for (int j =0; j<edges.length; j++)
            {
                String destination =(String) (((mxICell)edges[j]).getTerminal(false)).getValue();
                System.out.println("vertex-" + i + " is connected to " +
                        destination + " with weight " + (String)edge.getValue());
            }
            
        }
    }
```